# Newer SSRS instance with old Database Engine?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to install a SQL Server 2012 SP1 Reporting Services instance on "server A" that points to a SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Database Engine instance on "server B?"

I cannot seem to find any documentation that indicates interoperability between different versions of SQL Server Reporting Services and the Database Engine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install just reporting services on "server A". Make sure to choose feature installation and only check "Reporting Services - Native" on the feature selection screen.

When the installation is finished be sure to run through the configuration wizard and point your new reporting services to a database on "server B".