# SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) DB upgrade independent of source database

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

My client has two business databases running on SQL Server 2005, together with SSRS databases (`ReportServer` and `ReportServerTempDB`), all on the same W2K3 server. My client is thinking about separate the SSRS out from the server, moving to a W2k12 R2 server, and upgrade the SSRS databases to SQL Server 2014, but with the business databases remain on SQL server 2005/W2k3 (because of $$$).

Will that be possible and is that likely to experience problems in the future?
Thanks in advance.

p.s. I should also mention there are two .NET 4.0 C# apps connected to the business and SSRS databases atm. SSRS databases are full of overnight generated report snapshots, plus ad-hoc reports generated via the apps. The SSRS db is about 80GB.

Comment: I found the answer from here.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18903992/1193911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with BIDeveloper, the only way to really be sure of this is to test it. However, I can tell you from experience that so long as your report writers do not try to take advantage of new features found in the new sql server version that your SSRS instance is running off, you should be fine.

We had a similar situation where our databases were 2008r2, running on windows 2008r2 servers, but our SSRS was running on a windows 2012 server, with the SQL Server backing for SSRS was running on SQLServer 2012. - It was fine - so long as all the SSRS reports were able to run against the 2008r2 sql servers. We had a few bad report writers that tried to use sql server 2012 functions that didn't run on 2008, and those reports had errors. After the report writer fixed their mistake, the reports worked fine.

An example off the top of my head would be if a report writer wrote the following query to be executed in the report:

```
SELECT
    TRY_CONVERT(INT, 100) [SomeConvertedInt]
FROM
    <SOMETABLE>
```

It would work fine on their local development machine running SQL 2012, but would fail when the report was being executed on the SSRS server. To fix, they would have to remove the new 2012 function - in this case, TRY_CONVERT().

Comment: Can you give me one example, in your case, how a report writer is using sql server 2012 functions that didn't run on sql server 2008? Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  I guess in my case it is a straight migration without any programming changes.  Thanks for providing an example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new SSRS instance at the version you are proposing - without touching the old instance. Then do full testing.

*This is the only way to prove your plan will work.*